# Decode an encoded url in Django

Tags: python, django, post, urllib, urlencode

I am trying to send an encoded request to a Django server.

```
 import urllib
 params = urllib.urlencode({'msg':'encoded message'})
 f = urllib.urlopen("http://my.django.server", params) # Send request using POST
```

On the server side, I have the proper urlpattern in urls.py:

```
url(r'^msg/', 'myapp.views.msg', name='msg')
```

and method in views.py:

```
def msg(request):    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = request.POST.get('msg',None)
```

But I am getting a 404 error while accessing this url using the above way to access url. Most probably this is because Django is not able to match regex from encoded url. How can I decode this url at Django and make the flow work properly?

Python: 2.6.6

Django: 1.4.14

Answer (score 2):

According to the `urls.py` configuration, you need to use `msg/` endpoint:

```
f = urllib.urlopen("http://my.django.server/msg/", params) 
#                                     HERE ^
```